# Field Calculator, Conditional

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, data, field-calculator

I am trying to assign a value from one field of my attribute table to a new field based on the 3D field...

The code block I am thinking about is as follows:

```
def conditional (!FarmCateg!):
   if (FarmCateg=='4'):
       return 
        '''(and here I want to return values from "Percent Area" Field (float)):'''
   elif( ): return "0"
```

Expression: conditional(!FarmCateg!)

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this where I have assumed that the third field you are wanting to update is of type float or double ...

Code Block:

```
def conditional (FarmCateg,PercentArea):
   if FarmCateg == '4':
       return PercentArea
   else:
       return 0.0
```

Expression:

```
conditional(!FarmCateg!,!PercentArea!)
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped, but in line2 I didn't use apostrophe for number 4, since it was already calculated value...

Comment: @Irina From your Comment I am not clear whether this is now resolved.  If yes, but with a modification you made to the code I suggested, then I recommend that you edit my Answer to correct it and then Accept it.

Answer (score 1):

def conditional (FarmCateg,PercentArea):
   if FarmCateg == 4:
       return PercentArea
   else:
       return 0.0